# Azure Redis unable to connect to Redis servers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName 1.0.394` And I'm trying to connect to my Azure Redis, but I keep getting this error when I run my project:

```
RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); 
to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING
```

Oddly enough, if I use  `StackExchange.Redis 1.0.394` everything works fine, but I need StrongName version in order to use RedisSessionStateProvider.

Here is code for connecting to Redis:

```
private static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection == null || !_connection.IsConnected)
            {
                var config = new ConfigurationOptions();
                config.EndPoints.Add("myredisname.redis.cache.windows.net");
                config.Password = "myverylongkey";
                //in ms
                config.SyncTimeout = 5000;
                config.Ssl = true;
                config.AbortOnConnectFail = false;

                _connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(config);
            }

            return _connection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used the exact code you pasted above but was unable to reproduce the issue.  It works fine with both StackExchange.Redis 1.0.394 and StackExchange.Redis.StrongName 1.0.394.  Would you be able to share a working console app project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: For some very strange reason, now, it works for me to :S When I read your comment, I decided to give it one more shot on current project an then create console project, so once again I deleted StackExchange.Redis, and added StackExchange.Redis.StrongName and now it works. I don't know why, I've tried this and others things several times before, but now it works for some reason

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same exception and it turned out to be corporate  **firewall, which is blocking port 6379, 6380.**

I copied my test console app in an environment outside company network and connection was successful. 
So if Redis server is running on the internet and your network is behind a firewall make sure the ports are open.