# It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to make a simple example of reading and writing from azure redis cache and I get this error

> An exception of type 'StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException' occurred in StackExchange.Redis.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING

The code I am using is this, I changed dns and password

```
// Get Connection instance
ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer
    .Connect("xx.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=false,password=...");
// Get database
IDatabase databaseCache = connection.GetDatabase();
// Add items
databaseCache.StringSet("foo1", "1");
databaseCache.StringSet("foo2", "2");
// Add items with experation value
databaseCache.StringSet("foo3", "3", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

// Get item value
string foo1Value = databaseCache.StringGet("foo1");

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed);
return View();
```

Comment: Also, try to check for solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906891/cant-reconnect-to-azure-redis-via-stackexchange-redis/32852922#32852922

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Azure Redis Cache only enables the SSL endpoint by default.  The most secure approach is to set "ssl=true" when calling ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect().

Alternatively, you can use the Azure Portal to enable the non-SSL endpoint on your Azure Redis Cache, but then your password and all data will be sent in clear text.

Comment: This may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725437/azure-redis-unable-to-connect-to-redis-servers/29837033#29837033

Answer (score 6):

I had exact same exception and it turned out to be corporate  **firewall, which is blocking port 6379, 6380.**

I copied my test console app in an environment outside company network and connection was successful. 
So if Redis server is running on the internet and your network is behind a firewall make sure the ports are open.

Comment: as a remark : 
6380 port for SSL.
6379 port for Non-SSL connection.